Clone/copy of disk
I want to copy this Ubuntu server to another disk. It seems when I set it up the disk made a partition of 1.8T and only 100GB of that is being used by the server. I want to clone that to a second disk. As an end result I want to be able to plug the second disk in a computer and it would run like the original. I tried making snapshots and copying those, but I had no luck. If I go into Windows on sda and go to Macrium it sees the disk as full and wiztree can't even find the disk.


Will this help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1518808/cloning-and-restoring-partitions-using-gparted/1518811#1518811

You are of course aware that if the other computer has any hardware differences it may not work. Look at this app as a possible solution to make the clone. https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/
